# Capable of hosting filter related icons in Wice grid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wice-grid

I am trying to find a resource in solving this issue. I am using the wice grid gem for my project and I encounter this error `undefined method capable_of_hosting_filter_related_icons?' for nil:NilClass`. Below is my view:

```
-grid(@vendors_grid) do |g|                  
  g.column name: 'ID', attribute: 'ID'do |vendor|                    
  vendor                          

[...]                                 

  link_to('Edit', vendor_index_path(vendor))
```

I converted the erb example from the readme file to haml. I followed the install instructions carefully to ensure I do not miss anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this small correction `-grid(@vendors_grid).each do |g|` and try again. It could be that you are not enumerating over an array, in which case you are not getting back the right object

Comment: That took care of the error. @Jones Agyeman, I'm now getting a different error. `WiceGrid: Missing block for the grid helper`. I was reading through the api and added the other html, id and class attributes. No luck.

Comment: Mark this as an answer and open another question with the necessary error details and I will help you

Comment: Not sure if I did the marking correctly. I'll open another question.

Comment: Nope you didn't. Let me know when you open another question please

Comment: I just opened another question. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710412/wicegrid-missing-block-for-the-grid-helper]