# WiceGrid: Missing block for the grid helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wice-grid

I am continuing my project using the wice grid. The `undefined method capable_of_hosting_filter_related_icons?` error was resolved with the help of SO. I am not getting `WiceGrid: Missing block for the grid helper..` I was reading through the api and added the other html, id and class attributes. No luck. Below is my view:

```
-grid(@vendors_grid) do |g|                  
  g.column name: 'ID', attribute: 'ID'do |vendor|                    
  vendor                          

  [...]                                 

  link_to('Edit', vendor_index_path(vendor))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `g.column(name: 'ID', attribute: 'ID') do |vendor|`

Comment: Is your code public available on GitHub for me to run locally on my machine?

Comment: No it is not but I can push it. Will do that in a bit.

Comment: Project has been pushed. Here's the URL: https://github.com/shredthered/projectsample.git